# mpz_urandomb always giving same result

Tags: gmp

Whenever this code is executed, it gives the same result. I am not able to get a random value.

The value of temp always comes out as 6400306986398558324. (lambda = 256.)

```c
mpz_t group_size,temp;
mpz_init(group_size);
mpz_init(temp);
gmp_randstate_t state;
gmp_randinit_mt (state);
mpz_urandomb (temp, state,lambda);
mpz_nextprime (group_size, temp);

printf("temp : %ld \n",mpz_get_ui(temp));
printf("Group Size : %ld \n",mpz_get_ui(group_size));
```

Comment: Look for "seed" in the manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a seed for the state. From [official documentation](https://gmplib.org/manual/Random-State-Seeding.html#Random-State-Seeding):

> Function: `void gmp_randseed (gmp_randstate_t state, const mpz_t seed)`
>
> Function: `void gmp_randseed_ui (gmp_randstate_t state, unsigned long int seed)`

Here is example for your code (not really useful in real world as `time(NULL)` will return the same result for one whole second).

```
...
gmp_randinit_mt (state);
gmp_randseed_ui(state, time(NULL))
mpz_urandomb (temp, state,lambda);
...
```